# Taking Json from API and iterating over the results

Tags: vb.net

So I feel stupid for asking probably a easy question but I'm not very familiar with .NET and I've been googling for a while now.

I'm looking to take in data from a web API and be able to iterate over it. The data looks like this

```
[
   {"id":"5", "date":"01-01-2014"},
   {"id":"90", "date":"05-01-2013"}

]
```

What I've got so far:

```
 Private Sub newGetData()
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://somesite.com"), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)

        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList
        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            MsgBox(item.name)
        Next


        'usernameTextbox.text = jResults("name").ToString()
        'placenameTextbox.text = jResults("place")("name").ToString()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

I've tried a bunch of things but it always fails on the loop. How do I go about doing this?

EDIT: The error message for this one

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader   item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)
 at Forecasting.Form1.newGetData() in
```

Comment: Fail with what error message?

Comment: @tolanj I've added it to the question

Comment: Your JSON reply is malformed. I see an array containing JSON objects, but not as a JSON object itself. I guess you could wrap it by adding { "results": <your original data> } and then reading it of your JObject.parse method...